# Nginx rewrite to https from http on same server_name block when ssl is handled downstream

Tags: django, ssl, nginx

We have had this issue for ages now, and its starting to bite us in the ass. We run a site for a client written in python on the django framework. We then use nginx as a webserver/proxy for django. This is usually the most standard setup and works well.

The issue is that our client has another apache server higher up. That server handles the ssl termination and just passes requests to us via normal http. The apache server accepts both http and https on 2 domain names.

We can easily rewrite http to https on nginx level, but the issue comes in that a user can remove https and just use http.

Is there a way on nginx level to force users back to https://secure.example.com if they are on http://secure.example.com.

Thanks

Comment: "We can easily rewrite http to https on nginx level, but the issue comes in that a user can remove https and just use http" — could you explain that better? When you say "rewrite" you really mean "rewrite"? Or do you mean "redirect"? Does nginx know if the original request was with https, and how? Why can't you do the redirection in apache?

Comment: Yes, I meant redirect. nginx does not know if the request was https. We do not control apache, and trying to get anything done on that level is incredibly difficult. At this point, we are trying to see if we can just block port 80 on that ip.

Comment: But if nginx (and subsequently Django) doesn't know if the request was https, how could possibly either nginx or Django decide that a redirection is needed? I don't see any way without touching apache. Either apache must do the redirection, or apache should pass along the information of whether the original request was https (preferably the second).

Answer (score 1):

The usual technique is for the proxy handling ssl termination to add an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. The upstream application can then conditionally redirect when entering a secure area.

With `nginx` this could be accomplished using a `map`:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $insecure {
    default 1;
    https   0;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($insecure) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. Sadly, it just gives me redirect loops since it keeps thinking the request is insecure.

Comment: It *is* conditional on downstream providing you with the correct header.